# Variable number of RecyclerView items in multiple CardViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` whose items must be grouped in `CardView`s. There are a variable number of items that will be grouped in each `CardView` and the item `ViewType`s differ as well. I am struggling with how I can add items to each `CardView` such that it grows based on the number of items.

I have attempted using nested `RecyclerView`s but this has proved buggy.

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have attempted using nested `RecyclerView`s but this has proved buggy.

My implementation is what was buggy. The solution I settled on was to use nested `RecyclerView`s. A top level `RecyclerView` that would hold the `CardView`s and a `RecyclerView` in each `CardView` to display the variable number of items.

The reason my original implementation was "buggy" was because if the nested `RecyclerView` had no items to display, I set the `Visibility` to `GONE`. This was a poor attempt at optimization. This would cause issues where an item would dynamically be added to the nested `RecyclerView` but it wouldn't appear because the nest `RecyclerView` was set to `GONE`.

If you are using nested `RecyclerView`s, in your `onBindViewHolder()` method in the `Adapter` for the top level `RecyclerView`, be sure to update the items in the adapter of the nested `RecyclerView` or else it will contain recycled data meant for a different position.